# SharePoint WebPart forcing to fill out required fields to edit page

Tags: web-part, content-editor-web-part, check-out, sharepoint-site

A sharepoint page created by my predecessor which is a content viewer web part has some HTML "required" tags to fill out a form. When trying to checkout and edit this in the browser, it just hangs on "loading". In order to check out and edit the page I first need to fill in each of the required fields with random data (without submitting the form). I was wondering if there is some way around this, as there is no clear indication that this is the case( I figured it out through trial and error).

Comment: Is there another web part(or same web part) having input fields with required property on the same page?

Comment: to my understanding, this is the only webpart which has a link to a .html file and nothing else (within the webpart or anything on the site)